# Unable to compile C in eclipse juno

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, eclipse-juno

I have to date only been able to compile C code through the command line using the gcc -o extension.

I would ideally like some sort of IDE to help with debugging and productivity, but I am as yet having no luck.

Specifically in relation to Eclipse Juno, I am unable to get it to compile or debug any C code at all.

Just to make sure I had completed the neccesary prerequisites, I downloaded mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe , but the report log from it claimed that all elements of mingw were already installed.

On the Makefile Project settings in the New CDT Project Wizard subsection of preferences I have tried using Cygwin PE Parser and PE Windows Parser (separately and together).

[image: Eclipse Juno C compilation]

There is no difference when attempting to run as a local C Application

Answer (score 1):

Your MinGw is properly not set up. Edit your path variable in your PC to

C:\MinGW\bin;

C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

and try to compile.

Have you installed MinGW? It creates run time environment for C and CPP.

Comment: How would one edit the path variable? I also don't have any folder called 'msys' in my MinGW folder.

Comment: You have to install MinGW and while installing you will be given options on what do you want in your package. In that select on the C and C++ compiler and MYSYS basic system.   And to edit your path variable to go you MyComputer right click, Go to advance settings in there, go to Advanced Tab in pop up box, click on the Environment Variable, there is path in there in System Variable, click edit, paste path of your MinGW by putting semi colon (;)

Comment: Tried all that. C:\MinGW\bin; was already a path, but after extending the installation of MinGW, I also included  C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\local\bin; as a path. No change, at all, I'm afraid. :/

Answer (score 0):

Following are step to configure Eclipse CDT for fedora 17 and run a simple helloworld program. Proper configuration should eliminate most issue.

Install Eclipse Juno in Fedora 17

Using command line execute the following commands

```
su
yum -y install eclipse
yum -y install eclipse-cdt eclipse-cdt-sdk
eclipse
```

The above commands will install Eclipse with C/C++ development Tools (CDT) and C/C++ with SDK

**Confirm that Eclipse C/C++ Development tools are installed**

Help > Install New Software > Work with (Input Box) enter the following

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno
```

For more information refer to [Setting up Eclipse](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s04.jsp#installingcdt)

Using [Eclipse Juno C/C++ Development Getting Started](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_o_home.htm) test the environment.

**Create a Project from scratch using eclipse**

```
File > New > Project > c++ Project > Next
Enter Project Name > Select Empty Project > Tool chain Linux GCC > Next 
Select Debug and Release > Finish
```

**If Needed Add C/C++ file and Edit**

```
New > Source File > Source file Name: main.cpp
Enter or copy/paste code
Save All
Project > Build All
Run > Run
Review Console for output
```

Hope this is sufficient information get a program complied

References

- [How to install Eclipse IDE on Fedora 16 ....](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-eclipse-ide-on-fedora-16-verne.html#axzz36Jsl3Df1)
- [Setting up Eclipse CDT on Linux/Unix](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/cdt.jsp)
- [Eclipse C/C++ Development User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_o_home.htm)